# Dbeaver Level Function or column name

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, dbeaver

**There is a Column name Level** and **when I type Level in Dbeaver** it shows me two options:

1. Column name Level which if selected shows like **"level" in blue color** not normal black text
2. Second option - **Level probably as function in red**

Is this acceptable issue or should I ask Data engineer to change the name?

Is there any way to fix this variation in text format for column name?

Just noticed there are other column names like: Source, Type which when I type shows up in red in Dbeaver

Database- Amazon Athena

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot explaining a bit more about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Level, source, type - all these words you can find in the [SQL reserved words list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words). Usually, when the driver does not return a specific database reserved words list, DBeaver uses a standard list.
You can't turn off the backlight of specific words in DBeaver. But if you are sure, that "level, source, type" are not reserved words in the Amazon Athena - you can create an issue on DBeaver GitHub. And we removed these words from the keywords list for the Athena Database manually.